# Is it possible to create a link type in TFS 2010 to be specific what kind of work item is the target and what is the source

Tags: workitem

For example, I create level 1 2 3 three types of work items. then I want to customize a link type which only link level 1 to level 2, but can`t level 1 to level 3 directly. Is it possible? How?

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible at least from looking at the attributes of a linktype which are referenceName, ForwardName, ReverseName and TopologyType.  You can enforce a parent/child relationship that isn't circular but I don't believe you can say "and do not allow this WI type to be a child of this WI when linking."

You do have the ability to create custom link types; however, that will only insure a relationship and not scope it to work item type.

For example, out of the box the CMMI template you can create a bug that has a child of WI Requirement of type Scenario which typically isn't a supported workflow (and isn't if you are trying to be CMMI compliant).

I would take a look at [Working with Link Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd293527.aspx).